# Why am I able to mount NFS share simply because root on my machine has the same UID as the NFS owner?

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, nfs, freenas

I have recently set up a new FreeNAS machine at home and am beginning to tinker. I have previously had very little experience with network administration (and I have only been using Linux on my home machines for the past year or two).

I have been used to mounting an SMB share from a Synology DiskStation via CIFS on my Kubuntu machine, and I need to supply credentials to be able to do that. I have been doing some online searching on the topic, and I understand that NFS doesn't require login credentials to mount, although I believe UIDs on the client and NFS machine need to align for the mount to succeed (although I'm not certain my understanding on this is correct or complete).

I appear to have been able to successfully mount the NFS share from my FreeNAS machine, and I believe this is because I run the mount command with sudo, and the NFS share owner is root in FreeNAS, so the UID's on client and server are both 0 and this allows the mount to proceed?

If this is correct, I am wondering if anyone who connects a Linux machine on my home network and has su privileges for that machine can then mount the NFS share without any credentials?

If so, is there a way that I can restrict the ability to mount the share? Is this what Kerberos is for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone with a similar query:

I need to tinker further to be more confident, but from what I've gleaned tangentally from [Startpaging](https://www.startpage.com/), podcast listening & blog reading over the last few months, I believe my suspicions outlined towards the end of the question are correct. See one response from a Slashdot article about Lennart Poettering's ambitions to change how Linux home directories are managed: https://linux.slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=14839086&cid=59218868.

As per that post; "NFS has two security modes: swiss cheese UID based, secure but super complicated and fragile kerberos based".